# Laravel 5 Three-way One-to-Many Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, eloquent

I have database like this
 `opportunities`

- Id
- contact_id

`contacts`

- Id
- User_id

`users`

- id

User model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

public function Contact()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Customer\model\Contact');
} 
}
```

Contact model:

```
 class Contact extends Model
{
    public function Opportunity()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('Sale\Model\Opportunity');
   }
  public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
} 
}
```

Opportunity model

```
class Opportunity extends Model
 {
       public function Contact()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('Customer\Model\Contact');
    }
  public function User()
  {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User','Customer\Model\Contact','user_id','id');
  }  
}
```

When on controller

```
  $Opportunity = Opportunity::with('User')->paginate(10);
  print_r($Opportunity->User);
```

Show me wrong data.

Comment: when you do dd ($Opportunity) in relations shows the user?

Comment: $Opportunity is collection... You should do `foreach($Opportunity as $op) { print_r($op->User); }`

Comment: @coding-scripting yes show user. but it's not correct user. for example opportunities.id=1 and  opportunities.contact_id=1 ,opportunities.user_id=2 show user 1 not user 2

Comment: @ljubadr I know it's work but show me not correct data

Comment: Well for an exact definition of the user in the form create input for user_id and send user_id